# Need help adding a translation for "read more" button text in Fairy WordPress theme options

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation

I'm using a Wordpress theme called Fairy, which has Fairy theme options in the customization section. In the blog section options, there is a setting to change the "read more" button text for the blog and archive pages. I'm having difficulty translating this into two different languages. I cannot add a plugin to translate it because the "read more" text block is within the Fairy theme settings, not in Wordpress. Is there a way to add a translation?

[Text block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuZRu.png)

I tried translating it with different translation plugins, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could translate both themes and plugins. I do not understand what you mean by saying

> I cannot add a plugin to translate it because the "read more" text
> block is within the Fairy theme settings

Although, you could add [loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) plugin. This plugin scans all the themes and plugins by your preference and display all the texts for translation. Furthermore, plugin allows you to create a custom folder called languages inside your root folder, so you won't lose your custom translations in case of theme's updates or plugins.

Check it out and let me know if you need more help on your issue. If you are ok with that, please think about mark your question as answered to help others too

Another solution, if that helps:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'ds_translate_woocommerce_strings', 999, 3 );
function ds_translate_woocommerce_strings( $translated, $untranslated, $domain ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        switch ($translated) {
            case 'Read more': //text as it appears in your website
                $translated = 'New translate'; //what you actually want to appear
                break;
        }
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have installed the Loco Translate plugin and selected all the 'read more' buttons that I found to ensure that the one I need will be translated. I think the option I am looking for is 'Read more text for blog and archive page,' which I have already translated. However, even after translating all the buttons, it only appears in one language, and nothing seems to have changed. Perhaps there are additional settings that I need to adjust to make it work correctly?

Comment: "Read more text for blog and archive page" is actually a tooltip for the input field that following. According to your screenshot you wrote "Read more", thus you are looking for this text to translate inside Loco Translate.. In the end, which plugin you are using ? I have add a code snippet to my previous answer if that helps. check it out and let me know

Comment: I'm using Polylang. However, I was able to resolve the issue by utilizing the 'Add Polylang support for Customizer' plugin.